# Adobe Air Mobile: offline playback of DRM videos

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flex4.5, drm

I have videos with DRM using flash Access. I would like to be able to play these videos on mobile devices using Air when offline. It is possible to play streaming DRM content on mobile devices but I'm unsure how to save a voucher for offline playback. Since DRMManager is not included in Air Mobile, is this possible and how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If DRMManager is not available in the mobile runtime then there is no way to use it, simple as that. Welcome to the perils of coding in a scripting language, that is, being bound to the whims of the people who control the runtime source code.

Comment: Do you have any first hand knowledge of this? I'm not sure this is that simple (which is why I asked). Adobe has documented in different places how to stream DRM videos to mobile devices and they made a big deal about mobile devices having support for flash access 3. What I am unsure of is if it's possible to also play offline DRM content. What I think is needed is a way to download a voucher without using the DRMManager.

Comment: I'm speaking in regard to playing offline. If the classes/APIS for DRM are not present in the runtime then you're not going to be able to use them, right? You could possibly look into writing a native extension for AIR...  look into that.

Comment: True the DRMManager is not there but NetStream can still play content with DRM and handle DRM events. On the desktop when you do this the voucher will be cached for later use. If this is true for mobile as well then this may allow for the playing of offline videos. Problem is that I can't find any documentation on this. This doesn't leave me optimistic but I am looking for first hand knowledge rather than a guess.

Comment: I agree with you there and I'm not going to try and answer that question, my answer was simply to say that if you're relying on the DRMManager in any way and it's not present then you're SOL in that regard. I hope someone comes along with a better answer to your question. Have you tried just doing it yourself and seeing if it will work?

Comment: I haven't tried. Hacking at it was going to be the next step. I was hoping there is a tried and tested way of doing this. Maybe even something from Adobe. Since I couldn't find any other similar questions I figured I'd ask first.